# como usar dos sensores GP2Y0A21 con arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor

estuve trabajando con dos sensores GP2Y0A21 activando y desactivando focos, ahora quiero hacer lo mismo pero ingresando un delay cada que se active uno o el otro y si se activan los dos que no generen problemas, al momento de ingresar delays en mi codigo este solo me respeta una vez y de ahi entra en un bucle espero me ayuden

Anexo mi codigo;

```
**void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  if (analogRead(0) < 150) {
     digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
     delay(1000);
    
    
  }
  else{
    
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    delay(10000);
    
  }
  
 if(analogRead(1) < 150){
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
   
  }
  else{
    
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    delay(10000);
    
    }
}**
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar con más detalle el problema que tienes?Según tu código, en el momento en el que se desactiva un sensor, tu programa queda bloqueado durante 10s y en el momento en el que detecta algo, se queda bloqueado por 1s. ¿Tú problema es si tiene que detectar ambos obstáculos a la vez?

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta me resultó un tanto confusa, pero después de darle muchas vueltas creo entender.

Lo que sucede es que no entiendes lo que en verdad hace la función `delay()`. Esta función paraliza todo tu código, es decir, que nada puede ejecutarse mientras se esté contando el tiempo de la pausa. Tu llamas a la función delay todo el tiempo, cada vez que el loop se repite, dejando un dejando solo un pequeñisimo espacio de tiempo para que se la luz se encienda.

```cpp
void loop(){
    //se ejecuta primero esto
    delay(1000);
    //Pasado el tiempo se ejecuta esto
    delay(1000)
    //Se repite el loop
}
```

El uso de delay es muy práctico para la enseñanza como el blink, también para hacer test o para añadir cierta protección a la placa, pero se desaconseja su uso en aplicaciones más complicadas o profesionales. En su lugar, usa `millis()`.

La función `millis()` devuelve el número de milisegundos que ha transcurrido desde que se inició la placa de Arduino, tiene un máximo de 50 días, después de eso se va a reiniciar.

Se usa de la siguiente forma

```cpp
const int periodo = 1000; //Tiempo a esperar
unsigned long tiempoAnterior = 0; //Variable para calcular la diferencia, siempre debe iniciar en 0
 
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() {
    while(millis() - tiempoAnterior >= periodo){
        tiempoAnterior = millis() //para reiniciar el timer
        Serial.println("Hola");
        // espere [periodo] milisegundos
    }
    //Otro código se ejecuta al mismo tiempo
}
```

Este código lo que es hace es calcular la diferencia entre el tiempo desde el inicio hasta superar el periodo establecido. Por eso la variable `tiempoAnterior` se le asigna el valor de millis, para reiniciar el timer, si no se reinicia, el código siempre se va a ejecutar porque millis ya superó el periodo.

Traté de mejorar tu código, pero no estoy seguro si es lo que tu esperabas:

```cpp
const int periodo1 = 1000;
const int posperiodo1 = 10000;
unsigned long tiempoAnterior1 = 0;

const int periodo2 = 1000;
const int posperiodo2 = 10000;
unsigned long tiempoAnterior2 = 0;

bool activo1 = false;
bool activo2 = false;

bool posactivado1 = false;
bool posactivado2 = false;

void setup() {
    //Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if(!posactivado1){
        if (analogRead(0) < 150) {  
            activo1 = true;
            digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
        }
        if (activo1){
            if(millis() - tiempoAnterior1 >= periodo1){
                activo1 = false;
                posactivado1 = true;
                digitalWrite(8, LOW);
                tiempoAnterior1 = millis();
            }
        }
        else{
            tiempoAnterior1 = millis();
        }
    }
    else{
        if(millis() - tiempoAnterior1 >= periodo1){
                posactivado1 = false;
                tiempoAnterior1 = millis();
        }
    }
    
    if(!posactivado2){
        if (analogRead(0) < 150) {  
            activo2 = true;
            digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
        }
        if (activo1){
            if(millis() - tiempoAnterior2 >= posperiodo2){
                activo1 = false;
                posactivado1 = true;
                digitalWrite(7, LOW);
                tiempoAnterior2 = millis();
            }
        }
        else{
            tiempoAnterior2 = millis();
        }
    }
    else{
        if(millis() - tiempoAnterior1 >= posperiodo2){
                posactivado2 = false;
                tiempoAnterior2 = millis();
        }
    }

}
```